# Querying oracle clob column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a clob column. Searching based on the clob column content needs to be performed. However

`select * from aTable where aClobColumn = 'value';`

fails but

```
select * from aTable where aClobColumn like 'value';
```

seems to workfine. How does oracle handle filtering on a clob column. Does it support only the  'like' clause and not the =,!= etc. Is it the same with other databases like mysql, postgres etc

Also how is this scenario handled in frameworks that implement JPA like hibernate ?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649011/search-for-a-particular-string-in-oracle-clob-column

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, it's not allowed (this restriction does not affect `CLOB`s comparison in PL/SQL)
to use comparison operators like `=`, `!=`, `<>` and so on in SQL statements, when trying
to compare two `CLOB` columns or `CLOB` column and a character literal, like you do. To be
able to do such comparison in SQL statements, [dbms_lob.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1016668) function can be used.

```
  select * 
    from aTable 
   where dbms_lob.compare(aClobColumn, 'value') = 0
```

In the above query, the `'value'` literal will be implicitly converted to the `CLOB` data type. 
To avoid implicit conversion, the `'value'` literal can be explicitly converted to the `CLOB`
data type using `TO_CLOB()` function and then pass in to the `compare()` function:

```
  select * 
    from aTable 
   where dbms_lob.compare(aClobColumn, to_clob('value')) = 0
```

Comment: is this behaviour the same with all other data bases like postgres as well

Comment: @DevBlanked PostgreeSQl has `TEXT`(there is no `CLOB`) data type, and [allows](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/193dd/5) you use comparison operators to compare values of that data type to each other or a string literal.

Comment: Beware that "Functions with NULL or invalid input values for parameters return a NULL". This may be significant in some cases.

Answer (score 10):

how about

```
select * from table_name where to_char(clob_column) ="test_string"
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` only works for clobs that are less than 4000 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Clob's are large datatypes that can store massive data and hence many operators that support varchar operations will not work on Clob, but in PL/SQL some of them do like mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_sql_semantics.htm#g1016221

As you can see in the table `Like` is supported in both Sql and pl/sql for clobs, but `=` is not supported in SQL, but is in pl/sql

If you really need to you could convert to varchar in sql and compare like Tom Kyte mentions [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:367980988799) like this: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1878f6/1

```
select * from aTable where dbms_lob.substr( aClobColumn , length(aClobColumn), 1 )='value';
```

Answer (score 0):

So do not. Because if you want to compare the data - then it may be a situation where one value: `NULL` and the second `EMPTY_CLOB`
And it is for this method different matter!
It returns -1, although in terms of data - both values ​​should not contain.
Would be correct:

```
dbms_lob.compare (NVL (AUDIT_PAYLOAD_TEXT_DEC, Empty_Clob ()),  NVL (AUDIT_PAYLOAD_TEXT, Empty_Clob ()))
```