# oracle sql developer string literal too long bind variable for greater than 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle with PL SQL since I am a SQL Server guy. The table has a long column with text greater than 4000 characters. I am trying to do a select test to find the record and got an SQL Developer response of string literal too long, use bind variable

I looked up some posting and tried the following

```
declare
  tempCLOB CLOB;
  old_clob_content CLOB:= 'very long text';
begin
  select ID INTO tempCLOB
  from database.table
  where dbms_lob.compare(CLOB_FIELD, old_clob_content) = 0;
end;
```

When I run it, I get the following error

> ORA-06550 string literal too long

With SQL Server, I did not need to add the INTO, just confused with the error statement.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying oracle clob column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250014/querying-oracle-clob-column)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

In a table, a `varchar2()` is limited to 4000 characters.  Hence, there is no reason to compare the value to a `varchar2()` that exceeds that number.  There will be no equality.

That leads me to suspect that `testColumnName` is really a CLOB (as the error suggests).  In that case, you should compare it to a CLOB, not a `varchar2()`.

Comment: Also if you're comparing CLOBs, `=` won't work - use DBMS_LOB.COMPARE to test equality, or LIKE / INSTR for partial matches.